# Blob image at Report header

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I was trying to implement dynamic images(blob) at  report header (RTF template) but unable to accomplish with below method.

```
 <fo:instream-foreign-object content-type="image/jpg" xdofo:alt="An Image" >
 <xsl:value-of select=".//DLR_IMG"/></fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

Can any body guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got simple Solution for this problem 
We need to create sub template inside RTF body and call it in header part

```
<?template:Header_IMG?>

<fo:instream-foreign-object content-type="image/jpg" xdofo:alt="An Image" >
<xsl:value-of select=".//DLR_IMG"/></fo:instream-foreign-object> 
(as field code )

<?end template?>
```

Template call in header/footer

```
<?call-template:Header_IMG?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your XML file contains image data that had been stored as a BLOB in the
database, use the following syntax in a form field inserted in your template where you want the image to render at runtime:

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object content-type=”image/jpg” height="4 in" width="4 in"><xsl:value-of select=”.//IMAGE”/></fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

where

1. image/jpg is the MIME type of the image (other options might be: image/gif and image/png)
2. IMAGE is the element name of the BLOB in your XML data.
3. form field - need to know Adding Form Fields to a MS Word Document( https://wiki.smartsimple.com/wiki/Adding_Form_Fields_to_a_MS_Word_Document)

[code to place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCjTb.png)
[form field in msword document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/artJy.png)